# does the phrase "After failing the vocab test, they drowned themselves in jolly ranchers" have a gerund?

Tags: grammar, phrases, prepositions, gerunds, prepositional-phrases

**Question**

> "After failing the vocab test, they drowned themselves in jolly ranchers"

*Part 1 of Question*

is "after failing the vocab test" a gerund phrase?

If it is why? how do you identify whether it is a gerund phrase? Because someone told me it was but I dont think it acts as a noun

*Part 2 of question*

is "failing the vocab test" a prepositional phrase?

**Question 2**

**Question**

in

> " While preparing for the speech, Joe couldn’t help but worry about his entrance. "

is "While preparing for the speech" a gerund phrase?

Because I know that gerund has to be a verb acting as a noun.

But If we have the word "while" before something, doesnt the next string of words have to be a verb?

**Question 3**

in

> Hoping for a miracle, the doctors continued the surgery.

What does the particpial phrase "Hoping for a miracle" modify?

Comment: Shouldn't this be broken up into 3 separate questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to recognize what "acts like" means. A *gerund* is a verb form and it acts like a verb in that it has syntactic relationships that characterize verbs. For instance, a gerund can take an **object**:

> *failing* **the vocab test**

But a gerund also acts like a noun in that it can perform the functions in a sentence that nouns perform. For instance, a gerund can itself be an **object of a preposition**:

> after ***failing*** the vocab test

Is this any different from

> after their failure at the vocab test

Note that a prepositional phrase is

> Preposition + Object

That should take care of question the first, both parts. Question the second:

Consider the sentence

> While angry, I turn red.

The "string of words" (of length 1) after *while* is not a verb.

Question the third. In

> **Hoping for a miracle**, the doctors continued the surgery.

the **introductory participial phrase** (or some would say clause) is a nominative absolute. So-called *nominative* because it's associated with the subject of the following main clause. (Here it's the doctors who are hoping.) And so-called *absolute* because it's not closely tied to the syntax of the main clause.  We can say that the phrase modifies the subject *doctors* as it describes them, or we can say that it modifies the verb *continued* as it tells us the manner in which they proceeded to operate. Or both.